# Does CGFloat/NSTimeInterval lose accuracy

Tags: objective-c

Is there any accuracy lost when dividing a CGFloat by a NSTimeInterval?

I am trying to translate a NSTimeInterval to a UIView.frame.size.width and currently casting it to a float.

Comment: What sort of precision do you need? Both types have enough precision for most things that would end up being drawn on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `NSTimeInterval` is a typedef for a `double`, which is guaranteed to have at least as much precision as a `CGFloat` (`CGFloat` is defined as a `float` on 32-bit systems and a `double` on 64-bit systems).

So no, diving a `CGFloat` by an `NSTimeInterval` will not lose any accuracy (compared to dividing it by another `CGFloat` that is; floating-point math always has precision/accuracy worries).

Answer (score 1):

CGFloat can be a float and NSTimeInterval is a double. No loss of precision if you perform a division (your result is a double) but if you cast an NSTimeInterval to a CGFloat you may have loss of precision.